# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Auto Change Tracking does not index some records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

We have a fulltext index table set with `automatic change tracking`. After inserting some rows into this table and waiting for the crawl to be completed we found out that some lines were not indexed by the crawl. I even tried a `start full population`, but those rows are missing in the fulltext index.

Does anyone knows why does this happen?

Comment: thanks for correcting my English errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you are missing some records from the full text index, you should first try to **rebuild the full text index.**

Comment: I did a full population. Is not it enough? My understand is that full population = rebuild index, right?